# Angular 6 - Html fields accessing other html fields values

Tags: angular, angular6

I have two fields with cost values, which can be changed by a switch of currencies.

```
            <span >
              <span >Total Normal Rate:</span>
              <span >{{ getRate(item.normalRate) | currency: currency }}</span>
            </span>
            <span >
                <span >Total Special Rate:</span>
                <span >{{ getRate(item.specialRate) | currency: currency }} </span>                
            </span>
```

I want to have a third field which value should be the subtraction of the two above.

I know I have options to do it with variables in the component and binding. Question is if I can access the two fields values within the html file and subtract them? Could it all be handled in the html?

EDIT: I don't want to get the functions again, doing: getRate(item.normalRate) -  getRate(item.specialRate) in order not to do the calculations again.

Comment: If you absolutely want to do it only in HTML without calling the functions twice, you can store the values in hidden fields. See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zdy9xx).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can bind the value to any of valid attribute of element and get the attribute value by reference.

For example, I am using the `title` attribute of `span`

```
  <div>
      <span>Total Normal Rate:</span>
      <span #currency1 [title]="getRate(10)" >{{ currency1.title | currency: currency }}</span>
    </div>
    <div>
      <span>Total Special Rate:</span>
      <span #currency2 [title]="getRate(5)" >{{ currency2.title | currency: currency }} </span>
    </div>
    <div>
      <span>Total Special Rate:</span>
      <span>{{ currency1.title - currency2.title  | currency: currency }} 
  </span>
</div>
```

Note : You cannot use any random attribute of element. It must be valid and angular must be aware of it.

Working copy is here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ktogtc

Comment: Very nice answer.

Comment: Wow, such a brilliant answer! Have my respect sir.

Answer (score 0):

Of course. Angular takes a JavaScript-in-HTML approach. You should be able to do:

```
{{ (getRate(item.normalRate) - getRate(item.specialRate)) | currency: currency }}
```

provided that `getRate()` returns a number. [StackBlitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-k6af1d?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: Thanks, that's a good point, but I don't want to do the calculations in that function again. Should've mentioned it. Edited now...

Comment: In that case, you'll want to set the result to a view model property for the difference.

Comment: I feared that. Was hoping there is a way to put an id e.g. #normalRate and #specialRate and somehow do normalRate.value - specialRate.value, because it will perfectly fit all the rest of the structure.

Comment: Template variables only give you a reference to the element. They aren't a way to create a template-only variable declaration, to the best of my knowledge. Django, Nunjucks and others have ways you can do this, but not in Angular.

Comment: @KrisBonev - It could work if you did not have the `currency` pipe. The formatted value is more complicated to process in the template.